# How to use IHostedService in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous, asp.net-core

I have a class that call REST API. The API return new data every couple minutes. I want to do background tasks with hosted services so to call the API every 5 minutes. Is the code I have how is suppose to be? How is this different with BackgroundService?

```
public class APICaller : IHostedService
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(call, null, 0, 300000); //Every 5 minutes

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void call(object state)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.example.com/values/d=A");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var responseContent = response.Content;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good. Although I think you're better off calling [`_timer.Dispose()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.dispose) rather than `_timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0)`. But in the end, it probably won't matter since that's only run when your application is stopping anyway.

The implementation of `BackgroundService` is described here, along with an example of how to use it: [Implementing IHostedService with a custom hosted service class deriving from the BackgroundService base class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice#implementing-ihostedservice-with-a-custom-hosted-service-class-deriving-from-the-backgroundservice-base-class)

The `BackgroundService` class inherits from `IHostedService`. It just changes your implementation so that all you need to implement is `ExecuteAsync()`, instead of both `StartAsync()` and `StopAsync()`. It just makes your code a little simpler, kind of...